# problemas al enviar datos para crear reportes en laravel con dompdf

Tags: php, html

esta es mi función en el controlador estoy usando 3 tablas relacionadas pero no envía los valores de la ultima tabla.

```
 public function show($id)
{
        $formulario=DB::table('formulario as f')
        ->select('f.idformulario' ,'f.imagen' ,'f.fecha_hora','f.e_f_p','f.nombre','f.sexo','f.num_dni','edad','f.fecha_nacimiento')
        ->where('f.idformulario','=',$id)
        ->first();

        $detalle_familias=DB::table('detalle_familia as df')
        ->join('formulario as f','df.idformulario','=','f.idformulario')
        ->select('df.idformulario','df.nombre_familia','df.grado_parentesco','df.edad_familia','df.estado_civil_familia','df.grado_instruccion','df.ocupacion_familia','df.ingreso_economico')
        ->where('df.idformulario','=',$id)
        ->get();

        $detalle_familia_saluds=DB::table('detalle_familia_salud as ds')
        ->join('formulario as f','ds.idformulario','=','f.idformulario')
        ->select('ds.idformulario', 'ds.nombre_familia_problema', 'ds.descripcion_familia_problema')
        ->where('ds.idformulario','=',$id)
        ->get();

         $pdf = \PDF::loadView('formularios.ficha_historia_personal.show', compact('formulario',$formulario), compact('detalle_familias', $detalle_familias), compact('detalle_familia_saluds',$detalle_familia_saluds));
```

Ahora adjunto la vista .blade donde suge el error por que no esta recibiendo los datos de la ultiam tabla detalle_familia_salud.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
 <h1>totulo alumno</h1>
 <div class="contenido">
   <p>{{$formulario->e_f_p}}</p>
   <p>{{$formulario->nombre}}</p>
   <p>{{$formulario->sexo}}</p>
   <p>{{$formulario->num_dni}}</p>
   <p>{{$formulario->edad}}</p>
   <p>{{$formulario->fecha_nacimiento}}</p>

   @foreach($detalle_familias as $det_f)
   <p>{{$det_f->nombre_familia}}</p>
   <p>{{$det_f->grado_parentesco}}</p>
   @endforeach      
   <img src="/imagenes/foto/'.$formulario->imagen">
   <p>nada</p>

   @foreach($detalle_familia_saluds as $det_s)
   <p>{{$det_s->nombre_familia_problema}}</p>
   <p>{{$det_s->descripcion_familia_problema}}</p>
   @endforeach

  </div>  

  
</body>
</html>
```

io)->with('detalle_familia_saluds', $detalle_familia_saluds)->with('detalle_familia_saluds',$detalle_familia_saluds);
           return $pdf->stream('reporte.pdf');
    }

Ahora adjunto mi plantilla .blade

Comment: intenta con `compact('formulario','detalle_familias','detalle_familia_saluds')` con esto debería tener acceso a las variables en su vista.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo sos grande me soluciono el problema.